# AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute 'init'

Tags: python, pyttsx3

I was making a personal assistant. I got an error in starting code:

```py
import pyttsx3
engine = pyttsx3.init()
engine.say('How are you today?')
engine.runAndWait()
```

Error:

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pyttsx3/drivers/nsss.py:12: ObjCSuperWarning: Objective-C subclass uses super(), but super is not objc.super
  class NSSpeechDriver(NSObject):
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pyttsx3/__init__.py", line 20, in init
    eng = _activeEngines[driverName]
          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.11/3.11.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/weakref.py", line 136, in __getitem__
    o = self.data[key]()
        ~~~~~~~~~^^^^^
KeyError: None

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/anshtyagi/Documents/personal assistant/main.py", line 5, in <module>
    engine = pyttsx3.init()
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pyttsx3/__init__.py", line 22, in init
    eng = Engine(driverName, debug)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pyttsx3/engine.py", line 30, in __init__
    self.proxy = driver.DriverProxy(weakref.proxy(self), driverName, debug)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pyttsx3/driver.py", line 52, in __init__
    self._driver = self._module.buildDriver(weakref.proxy(self))
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pyttsx3/drivers/nsss.py", line 9, in buildDriver
    return NSSpeechDriver.alloc().initWithProxy(proxy)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pyttsx3/drivers/nsss.py", line 15, in initWithProxy
    self = super(NSSpeechDriver, self).init()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute 'init'
sys:1: UninitializedDeallocWarning: leaking an uninitialized object of type NSSpeechDriver
```

I don't know what is the problem. One more thing: due to some issue I had to uninstall old python version on Mac and installed new one using Homebrew.

Mac OS ventura 13.4

Python 3.11

Comment: sorry, can't recreate , works okay for me(on mac Catalina, and pyttsx3 version 2.90), I think some dependency is missing for `pyttsx3`, try to reinstall `pyttsx3` and look for warnings.

Comment: I reinstalled it but no fix also their are no warnings while installing it.

Comment: @simpleApp check above

Comment: created the virtual env and was able to recreate the problem. problem is with driver (`nsss`) [https://github.com/nateshmbhat/pyttsx3/blob/master/pyttsx3/drivers/nsss.py]

Comment: @simpleApp same issue in venv

Answer (score 27, accepted):

this turns out to be a little tricky. and this is a workaround! hope works for you.

Under the hood, this module `pyttsx3` uses PyObjC as a bridge between Python and Objective-C.

Step 1: Check that `pyobjc` is installed(`pip show pyobjc`), if not install as `pip install pyobjc`. 
Step 2: open this file `/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pyttsx3/drivers/nsss.py` and change the following:

```
#self = super(NSSpeechDriver, self).init() comment this line , and add the following
self = objc.super(NSSpeechDriver, self).init()
```

[image]

**Note**: `from Foundation import *` imports `NSObject` and objc from foundation, which has been consumed.

after the change, your following program would run okay.

```
import pyttsx3
engine = pyttsx3.init()
engine.say('How are you today?')
engine.runAndWait()
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the supported Python versions are 3.5 to 3.7, as stated in the documentation. I can confirm that version 3.6.15 works fine with my Mac. (However, version 3.7.12 doesn't work.)

Answer (score -1):

You may also need to add to your nsss.py file

```
import objc
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour] and read [answer], and note well that this is **not a discussion forum**. If you think that an existing answer is missing a step, consider proposing an edit to the answer. At 50 reputation you can leave comments with feedback on answers by others. But at any rate, the answer section is **only** for attempts to answer the question, as written.