# AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute 'init' sys:1: UninitializedDeallocWarning: leaking an uninitialized object of type NSSpeechDriver

Tags: python, pyttsx3

While creating an assistant and trying to convert audio to speech using pyttsx3, but everytime I run my program, I get the same error "AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute 'init'
sys:1: UninitializedDeallocWarning: leaking an uninitialized object of type NSSpeechDriver".

I have tried to uninstall it, and then use an earlier version, but the outcome was still the same. Is there a solution to this? I have looked at this [AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute 'init'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76434535/attributeerror-super-object-has-no-attribute-init)
but the solution did not work for me. Is there anything wrong in my code?

```
import os
import time
import pyaudio
from gtts import gTTS
import speech_recognition as sr
import playsound
import pyttsx3

engine = pyttsx3.init()


lang = 'en'

while True: 
    def recordAudio():
        said = ""
        
        r = sr.Recognizer()
        with sr.Microphone() as source:
            audio = r.listen(source)
            said = r.recognize_google(audio)

            engine.say(said)
            engine.runAndWait()
                 
            
    
    recordAudio()
```

Error I got

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pyttsx3/drivers/nsss.py:12: ObjCSuperWarning: Objective-C subclass uses super(), but super is not objc.super
  class NSSpeechDriver(NSObject):
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pyttsx3/__init__.py", line 20, in init
    eng = _activeEngines[driverName]
          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/weakref.py", line 136, in __getitem__
    o = self.data[key]()
        ~~~~~~~~~^^^^^
KeyError: None

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/akdas/Desktop/Voice-Activated-Calculator/main.py", line 9, in <module>
    engine = pyttsx3.init()
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pyttsx3/__init__.py", line 22, in init
    eng = Engine(driverName, debug)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pyttsx3/engine.py", line 30, in __init__
    self.proxy = driver.DriverProxy(weakref.proxy(self), driverName, debug)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```